# DirectX CreateBuffer Memory Leaks

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, directx, direct3d

I want to write a benchmark app to test write speed from system memory to GPU memory using DirectX api. But even if I just createBuffer and release in a for loop, the memory diagnosis tools shows that the process's private bytes size is constantly increasing. I think it might be because GPU mapped system memory is never released. BTW, The heap size is stable.

```
 1. FOR 1000 iteration
 2. CreateBuffer using 
               D3D11_USAGE_STAGING/D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC 
               & D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE
 3. d3dbuffer.Release & d3dbuffer = nullptr
```

Is there anyone could explain how to properly release it? Is this the so-called mapped AGP memory?

Answer (score 1):

Direct3D uses delayed resource destruction. If you want to force all resources to be cleaned up, you need to call `Flush`. Writing effective Direct3D benchmarks is quite challenging as there are many things at play you are probably missing.

For some sense of this, read [Accurately Profiling Direct3D API Calls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172234(v=vs.85).aspx) and see [Profiling DirectX Apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj585574(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Thank you Chuck. for every iteration, I call flush and and query for command buffer empty signal. But when i use visual studio 2015 diagnostic tools to check memory usage it is still increasing and never go down. The app will crash when system memory is exhausted. The article explains very well about profiling api costs, but did not cover enough info on memory management. Any more ideas to limit buffer size? Thank you so much!

Comment: I have also use ID3D11Debug and debug device to verify that no d3d objects were leaked. Heap is stable. But the private bytes keeps going up per a few iterations. Eventually the app crashes when running of available 16GB memory.